# Additional comma in the end of aggregates in C++98 / C++03

Tags: c++

Why i can't use additional comma in the end of the initializer-list of aggregates in C++98 / C++03?

**ISO/IEC 14882:2003**

> 8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]
>
> = initializer-clause ( expression-list ) initializer-clause: assignment-expression { initializer-list ,opt } { } initializer-list:
>   initializer-clause initializer-list , initializer-clause

There are additional comma after initializer-list with opt specifier, right? Why i can't use it?

Comment: I get compile-time error when i try to use it in C++98 / C++03 mode

Comment: Because your compiler is buggy.

Comment: This is when you post the actual compiler error. It's anybody's wild guess without knowing a) the compiler and b) the actual error.

Comment: I can't imagine for what to use this feature

Comment: @Jupiter- It makes it a lot easier to build a C or C++ code generator that emits brace-initialized code.  You don't have to special-case the last element of the list.

Comment: @Jupiter-, and you can conditionally exclude any elements without consideration for the deliminating commas.

Comment: @Jupiter: it also helps with diffs. If you don't have to add/remove the last comma when adding to/removing from a list, the line won't show up as changed, which makes the diffs both smaller and quicker to review.

Comment: @templatetypedef In a lot of situations special-casing the last element can be tricky, but special-casing the first is almost always trivial (`bool isFirstItem;`).  You can think about generating items like `, someItem` with a special case of the first item not having the comma.

Answer (score 2):

The standard is pretty clear here: the trailing comma *is* allowed (a similar feature exists for declarations of constants within enums). The fact that you can't use it is a matter of the quality of implementation that you're using.

Comment: So, additional comma at the end of arrays is allowed in C89 / C90, C99, C11, C++98, C++03 and C++11, but additional comma at the end of enum initializer-list allowed only in C99, C11 and C++11?